# How to a read each line in text file and separate each word in an array in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to read a text file in angularJs by each line using a delimiter and want to store that delimited value in a var in angularJs. Here is my full code to read a text file. The problem I am facing here is only first line can be read and lines are being abandoned. And I want to display in the view using ng-repeat..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
$scope.freqch = [];
        $scope.getfreqchannel = function () {
            $scope.myPromise = genericService.genericFunction('GET', 'Lcn', null, $scope.device.deviceSerial);
            $scope.myPromise.then(function (results) {
                if (results.length > 2) {
                    var splits = results.split('');
                    _.forEach(splits, function (value) {
                        if (value.length > 0) {
                            var fcsplit = value.split(':',1);
                            var chs = fcsplit[1].split(':');
                            var n = {};
                            n.freq = fcsplit[0];
                            n.chs = _.filter(chs, function (o) { return o.length > 0; });
                            $scope.freqch.push(n);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.getfreqchannel();
```

And here is my some text that contains in the text file.

```
1:ACT INFO:11910
2:ACT CITY:10101
3:ACT_SHOW_TIME:10511
4:KF TV:11920
8:KASTHURI TV:10504
9:ZEE KANNADA:10207
10:KALKI KANNADA:14318
11:HOME SHOP 18:10828
12:COLORS KANNADA:10615
13:ASIANET SUVARNA:10409
14:UDAYA TV:10606
15:NAAPTOL KANNADA:14316
16:SARAL JEEVAN:14354
17:UDAYA MUSIC:10201
19:RAJ KAN MUSIC:11710
20:CHINTTU:11906
22:UDAYA COMEDY:10216
23:JANTAA TV:11015
24:SRI SHANKARA:11102
25:SUVARNA PLUS:10213
26:REAL TV:11724
```

Here I want the these sequence number like 1,2,3...26 to be stored in one variable and text to be stored in another variable.
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

It's not a case for angular but just JS.

Here's a working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/c0ykx9hg/

```
var textFile = `1:ACT INFO:11910
2:ACT CITY:10101
3:ACT_SHOW_TIME:10511
4:KF TV:11920
8:KASTHURI TV:10504
9:ZEE KANNADA:10207
10:KALKI KANNADA:14318
11:HOME SHOP 18:10828
12:COLORS KANNADA:10615
13:ASIANET SUVARNA:10409
14:UDAYA TV:10606
15:NAAPTOL KANNADA:14316
16:SARAL JEEVAN:14354
17:UDAYA MUSIC:10201
19:RAJ KAN MUSIC:11710
20:CHINTTU:11906
22:UDAYA COMEDY:10216
23:JANTAA TV:11015
24:SRI SHANKARA:11102
25:SUVARNA PLUS:10213
26:REAL TV:11724`;


// angular controller
var lines = textFile.split('\n');
$scope.myData = {};

angular.forEach(lines,function(line){
    line = line.split(':');
    $scope.myData[line[0]] = {
      data1: line[1],
      data2: line[2]
    };
});
```

Comment: Your Code is working, Thank you dear krutkowski86. .